# TableView data encoding in JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Maven JavaFX project in Eclipse and Firebird Database with *UTF-8* tables encoding (data in tables in russian language). When I try run it from Eclipse with command `jfx:run` - it was successfully and in TableView i see all data is correct.

[image]

But, when I try create native installer with command `jfx:native` and setup result package, all data in TableViews is incorrect encoding (search by internet get hint, that need convert data from *UTF-8* to *WINDOWS-1251)*.

[image]

Code to populate data from database:

```
private class GetClientListTask extends Task<ObservableList<Client>> {
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Client> call() throws Exception {
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(App.DB_CONNECTION_STRING, App.DB_USERNAME, App.DB_PASSWORD)) {
                com.zvpblog.KomstarService.model.jooq.tables.Client t = com.zvpblog.KomstarService.model.jooq.tables.Client.CLIENT;
                DSL.using(connection).
                selectFrom(t).
                orderBy(t.CLIENTID.desc()).
                fetch().
                map(rs -> new Client(rs.getClientid(), DateTimeUtils.convertToLocalDate(rs.getRegdate()), rs.getLname(), rs.getFname(), rs.getMname(), rs.getGender(), DateTimeUtils.convertToLocalDate(rs.getBirthdate()), rs.getAddress(), rs.getPhone())).
                forEach(c -> clients.add(c));
                clientTableViewData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(clients);
                return clientTableViewData;             
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
                return null;
            }       
        }
    }
```

Why in run mode encoding is correct, but in native package is incorrect?

Comment: I see that the headers are fine. Where do you populate the data from?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Yes, all UI elements labels is fine, only data from database is incorrect encoding. Add code to post (i call service in `Platform.runLater` in `init` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set connection properties `charSet` and `encoding` to `UTF8` solved the problem with populate data from database and insert data to database.

```
...
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
...
connectionProperties.put("charSet", "UTF8");
connectionProperties.put("encoding", "UTF8");
...
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(App.DB_CONNECTION_STRING, App.connectionProperties)
...
```